# Merge connection & configuration related tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[configure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configure) & [configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configuration) should be merged [(although I think they both should be removed)](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5933/165729).

Some of the following should be merged:

- [connect](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connect)
- [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection)
- [connectivity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connectivity)
- [disconnects](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disconnects)
- [disconnection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disconnection)
- [disconnected](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disconnected)
- [reconnect](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reconnect)

> [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection):
>
> All connections, wired, wireless, internet, intranet, and cable fall
>   under this category. Use this tag if your issue involves establishing,
>   maintaining, adding, or removing connections.

- [slow-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slow-connection)
- [wireless-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-connection)
- [network-connections](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-connections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [connect](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connect)
- [connectivity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connectivity)
- [disconnects](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disconnects)
- [disconnection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disconnection)
- [disconnected](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disconnected)
- [reconnect](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reconnect)
  All merged into [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection)
- [slow-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slow-connection)
  Also merged into [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection)
- [wireless-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-connection)
  Merged into [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking)
- [network-connections](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-connections)
  Merged into [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking)

[configure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configure) and [configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configuration) are [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.